# Bootstrap 3 Glyphicon wrench isn't working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap (3.0.0) and trying to put this on my webpage:

`<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span>`

Every other glyphicon seems to be showing up except the wrench which is just an ASCII square.

Comment: Working normally here: **http://jsfiddle.net/thiagobraga/eAPAj/**. Try to download again Bootstrap. Are you using LESS to build the CSS files? Check if `glyphicons.less` isn't commented in your `bootstrap.less`.

Comment: I have this going on right now as well.  Did you figure this out?

Comment: Sorry. I didn't find a solution.

Comment: @thiagobraga it probably works for you because you have old working version cached in your browser. Your fiddle shows an ASCII square for me.

Comment: Sorry. I tried too and see the square. Like you've said in your answer, changing the fiddle to the most recent Bootstrap version works correctly. [jsfiddle.net/thiagobraga/eAPAj](http://jsfiddle.net/thiagobraga/eAPAj)

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue with http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css.
Referencing http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css solves the problem for me.

***Demos***:

[3.0.0](http://jsfiddle.net/tuuD7/4/) - doesn't work

[3.0.2](http://jsfiddle.net/tuuD7/1/) - works fine

***UPD***:

looks like v3.0.3 is out now - http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css

[3.0.3](http://jsfiddle.net/tuuD7/5/) - works fine too